# OpenGL ES antialiasing with rendering using GL_LINES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, antialiasing, multisampling

I am struggling to render smooth lines using GL_LINES.
I have borrowed the MultisampleConfigChooser from the following link: [MultisampleConfigChooser.java](https://github.com/Awevation/Spuzzle/blob/master/src/com/awevation/spuzzle/MultisampleConfigChooser.java)

It seemed to find the multisample configuration without any errors.
Here is the code I use to render the lines on the screen:

```
    GLES20.glUseProgram(this.lineDrawProgram);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, 2,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            6*4, linesData);

    linesData.position(2);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mColorHandle, 4,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            6*4, linesData);

    linesData.position(0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, matrix, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, this.numLines*2);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
```

Blending is enabled with GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.
One more mention is that I am drawing the lines to a texture which is bound to an FBO as a color attachment. I have not added any extra code to enable multisampling for the FBO.

Here is the code I use to setup the FBO and texture:

```
    int[] fbo = new int[1];
    int[] tex = new int[1];
    enGLES20.glGenTextures(1, tex, 0);
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fbo, 0);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0]);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GLES20.GL_RGBA, this.width, this.height, 0,GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[0]);
    GES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0], 0);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The resulting lines still look like crap:
[image: screenshot]

Please help me get these lines to look smooth.
BTW *there are many different small lines in the screenshot, no curved lines or anything exotic.*

Comment: *"I am drawing the lines to a texture which is bound to an FBO "* - If you want multisampling, then you have to use the sampler type [`GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Sampler_types), instead of `GL_TEXTURE_2D`! See alos [Allocating a Multisample Render Target](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling#Allocating_a_Multisample_Render_Target)

Comment: I saw that somewhere, however there is no such thing as GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE... Only GL_TEXTURE_2D. Could the opengl bindings for Java be incomplete?

Comment: Multisampled render to texture is in OpenGL 3.2 standard but it is not provided in OpenGL ES by default. There is an extension which can be enabled in OpenGL ES (2.0) - [GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture.txt).

Comment: Is it at all possible to use extensions in OpenGL ES 2.0 in Java? I couldn't find any examples of it.